# Mcedit not seeing Minecraft App on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, minecraft-bedrock-edition, mcedit

I'm trying to configure Mcedit for Minecraft and the version of Minecraft I'm running was purchased and installed through the app store on Windows 10. Mcedit is unable to see the `.minecraft` file; so in other words it doesn't see Minecraft. I've done some research and see the install folder:

```
C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

However this folder doesn't appear to have the `.minecraft` file. Can anyone give me some pointers on getting this setup correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The version of "Minecraft" you find on the Windows Store is actually called "Minecraft: Bedrock Edition", and is essentially the same as the one found on Xbox One, Nintendo Switch, iOS, Android and Gear VR. To use MCEdit on this version, you'll need to install a specific version called *MCEdit Unified*. It can be downloaded from [the official website](https://www.mcedit-unified.net/).

Once it has been installed on your PC, you need to load your Bedrock save. Worlds of this kind are located in:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
```

where `<username>` is your username (in your case, `david`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately after continued research I have found that mcedit does not support the Windows 10 version of Minecraft (purchased through the app store). I was able to find this information on the Mcedit website.

Comment: There is a version for MCPE, I think it's called "unified".